# Use Python without installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I have an installer which uses a Python script to install several components. I do not want to install Python on the users computer if they do not already have it and I also do not want having Python installed to be a prerequisite for using my installer. Is there a way of downloading Python without using the installer and just running it from a directory which can be easily removed after the installation is complete?

Answer (score 4):

[Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/) is an easy tool to use on Windows. If you want to create .exe programs use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to compile them. They can both work on top of each other, you can compile (make .exes) using Portable Python, Portable Python 3 is also available.

Comment: That is form 2014. Anything more 2022ish?

Answer (score 2):

If the installer is for OS X or Linux, Python shall be there usually. Otherwise

- Lazy way: Detect if Python is existed. If not, ask user to install it as dependency. e.g. A link for python [download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
- Rewrite your script. If the logic is not complicated, use some other build-in shell script is a good idea.
- Static linking Python. Yes, [static linking is evil](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/no_static_linking.html). However, it's still an option.
  Found some project maybe helpful on [github](https://github.com/bendmorris/static-python) and [google-code](https://code.google.com/p/pts-mini-gpl/wiki/StaticPython)

Answer (score 0):

(In addition to Owens points). Use py2exe or one of the other exe builder utils for python on windows.  On other platforms just use the python script.

Answer (score 0):

Try cx_Freeze

This program can freeze your python code into a .exe file and some other pyd files, it can be **run without installing python**.

NOTE: You will need to install python to freeze, but **you don't need python to run the program**.

You can download from here.

https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/index.html

TO FREEZE:
make a file `setup.py`
type

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup (name='NEW_EXE_FILE_NAME',
   executables = [Executable("xx.py")])
```

xx.py will be the python code you want to freeze.

command line: `python setup.py build`

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's embeddable package, available here:
[Python Windows Releases](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Once you download the package all you need to do is extract it into a folder. That's it... Installed.
You also might want to install pip to manage packages by running the pip install script [pip install script](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) and add pip.exe's relative path to python3xx._pth file.
PatriTech made a nice summary of the process on YouTube: [Embedded Python Installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQj4b7azNLY)