# Python how to create virutal environment and use external libraries without being installed

Tags: python, automation, virtualenv

I am trying to automate a maintenance process which involves os commands and DB commands. My script/project will be deployed on a server which has access to other machines in the cluster I need to submit few commands on other servers as well. i don't have access to install or upgrade python version or I can't do any extra installation online(via pip). I need a solution how I can use external libraries without being installed(someway to download and store) and also capability to maintain my own version of python(something like portable python). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to use Docker? You can fetch the docker image with already installed python or create your own, customized for your purposes

Comment: Consider using Portable Python, similar issue is mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210351/use-python-without-installing

Comment: actually I dont have enogh knowledge on docker but i guess even for that i need to install docker on my server right?? i don't want any installation to happen just need to copy scipts and should do.

Comment: @Damian my servers are linux servers cant use that  approach py2exe , i guess

Comment: Oh, sorry! I though there is version on linux, but you're right, it's windows-only ;(